# Not able to call a PowerShell script from another script

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, powershell-5.0

I am trying to call a file *enable.ps1* from another file *begin.ps1*. Both the files are in the same folder. So, I thought that may be I can use the following code for that purpose.

Here is the code I have written inside *begin.ps1* for calling.

```
#
# begin.ps1
#



function MapDrives ($Message)
    {
        Write-Host Network drives does not exist till now. Trying again to connect
        Write-Host ...............................................................
        WriteInLogFile "Network drives does not exist till now. Trying again to connect"

        $ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName
& "$ScriptPath\enable.ps1"


        cmd /c pause | out-null
        Start-Sleep -s 20
    }
```

There is the PowerShell file I am trying to call: ***enable.ps1***

- I am using Visual studio 2015
- Windows 7
- PowerShell 5
- both begin.ps1 and enable.ps1 are under same folder location which is this :

  C:\Users\srijani.ghosh\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\test\test

Do you have any idea on how should I proceed on this ?

P.S : did some changes as suggested by Martin. Now the code looks like this:

```
function MapDrives ($Message)
{
    Write-Host Network drives does not exist till now. Trying again to connect
    Write-Host ...............................................................
    WriteInLogFile "Network drives does not exist till now. Trying again to connect"

    $ScriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
    & "$ScriptPath\enable.ps1"


    cmd /c pause | out-null
    Start-Sleep -s 20
}
```

And, I am trying to run it in PowerShell ISE. It giving this error.

```
Network drives does not exist till now. Trying again to connect
...............................................................
& : The module 'param($Message)
    Write-Host Network drives does not exist till now. Trying again to connect
    Write-Host ...............................................................
    WriteInLogFile "Network drives does not exist till now. Trying again to connect"
    $ScriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
    & "$ScriptPath' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module param($Message)
    Write-Host Network drives does not exist till now. Trying again to connect
    Write-Host ...............................................................
    WriteInLogFile "Network drives does not exist till now. Trying again to connect"
    $ScriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
    & "$ScriptPath'.
At C:\Users\srijani.ghosh\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\test\test\begin.ps1:45 char:7
+     & "$ScriptPath\enable.ps1"
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (param($Message)...cmd \enable.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right. However it looks like `$ScriptPath` doesn't contain any value (as you see within the error message).

You probably have to **replace**

```
$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName
```

with

```
$ScriptPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that is not working either :(

Comment: How do you execute the begin.ps1 script?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015 for that.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Can you try to execute the script using powershell?

Comment: Why can't he just use `$PSScriptRoot`?

Comment: @MartinBrandl . let me try. Thanks :)

Comment: @TToni He will probably run into the same issue. I know he is using PS 5 but since he is using this within VS, they might be more ppl using the script so I thought providing the snippet which works with older PowerShell version would be better.

Comment: @MartinBrandl edited the question and added the new error log

Comment: What are you doing? Can you please remove the scripts within your post and just add two files with a single write-host ouptut where one file call the other? You are making the problem much more complicated then it is

Comment: Thanks @TToni .. working just fine with $PSScriptRoot.

Comment: @MartinBrandl , I have removed the unnecessary code. But, as per your suggestion, when I changed the code, it was showing something which was in my code body. So, I added the whole function just for the reference. Thanks !